# ExtJS RightToLeft

Tags: javascript, extjs

In ExtJS I need to change the places of afterPageText and beforePageText the code below is the class I'm using to extend, because ExtJS is lacking rtl support and thus I need the total number of pages to be written before the input box and not after but all I get is just the plain beforePageText without the total number. Thanks for helping in advance

```
Ext.namespace("Spc");    
Spc.HebPaging = Ext.extend(Ext.PagingToolbar, {
    initComponent: function(){
        var T = Ext.Toolbar;
        var config = {
                displayInfo: true,
                displayMsg: 'מוצג {0} - {1}, מתוך {2} ערכים',
                emptyMsg: "אין ערכים להציג",
                beforePageText: 'מתוך {0}',
                afterPageText: 'עמוד'
        };

        var pagingItems = [this.first = new T.Button({
            tooltip: this.firstText,
            overflowText: this.firstText,
            iconCls: 'x-tbar-page-first',
            disabled: true,
            handler: this.moveFirst,
            scope: this
        }), this.prev = new T.Button({
            tooltip: this.prevText,
            overflowText: this.prevText,
            iconCls: 'x-tbar-page-prev',
            disabled: true,
            handler: this.movePrevious,
            scope: this
        }), '-', this.beforeTextItem = new T.TextItem({
            text: String.format(this.beforePageText, 1)
        }),
        this.inputItem = new Ext.form.NumberField({
            cls: 'x-tbar-page-number',
            allowDecimals: false,
            allowNegative: false,
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            selectOnFocus: true,
            submitValue: false,
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                keydown: this.onPagingKeyDown,
                blur: this.onPagingBlur
            }
        }), this.afterPageText,
        '-', this.next = new T.Button({
            tooltip: this.nextText,
            overflowText: this.nextText,
            iconCls: 'x-tbar-page-next',
            disabled: true,
            handler: this.moveNext,
            scope: this
        }), this.last = new T.Button({
            tooltip: this.lastText,
            overflowText: this.lastText,
            iconCls: 'x-tbar-page-last',
            disabled: true,
            handler: this.moveLast,
            scope: this
        }), '-', this.refresh = new T.Button({
            tooltip: this.refreshText,
            overflowText: this.refreshText,
            iconCls: 'x-tbar-loading',
            handler: this.doRefresh,
            scope: this
        })];

        Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
        Spc.HebPaging.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

Ext.reg('Heb-Page', Spc.HebPaging);
```

Comment: can you post this in http://jsfiddle.net/ and then we can take a look

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `beforePageText` should in fact be:

```
beforePageText: '{מתוך {0',
```

It wouldn't be able to match `0}` properly.

Comment: didn't help, because the paging items dont override the original paging items in the PagingToolbar class

Comment: Try changing from `initComponent` to `constructor`. You shouldn't be messing with `initialConfig`, just call the constructor like this: `Seb.HebPaging.superclass.constructor.call(this, config)`.